# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no profile

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de crear un model perfil para el usuario general que tiene por defecto Django, pero parece que al crear un usuario desde el `manage.py` me sale el error que tiene el título junto con este otro:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: userprofiles_profile.birth_date
```

Este es el `models.py` de la aplicacion Profile

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

No sé si los signals tengan algo que ver con el inconveniente que estoy presentando y no sé si necesitan alguna otra parte del código para ayudarme a resolver este problema.

Gracias de antemano a quién pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus campos `bio`, `website` y `birth_date` son `NOT NULL`, Django lo crea de esta forma por defecto si es que no lo indicas explícitamente.

Modifica tu modelo para que estos campos acepten valores nulos ya que al momento de crear el perfil con el signal no tienes estos valores a la mano:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Vas a tener que correr una migración para que los cambios tengan efecto.

Comment: aah, con que era esta tonteria, yo pensaba que con el default se resolvia y por eso lo coloqué. Esto no lo olvidaré x.x Muchas gracias, @César